$UU^*$ by columns
Background
Let $U\in \mathbb(C)^{n \times m}$ with $m<n$ have the columns $u_k$. Namely,
$$U = \begin{pmatrix}
    \vert &  & \vert \\
    u_1   & ... & u_m   \\
    \vert &  & \vert
\end{pmatrix}$$
Note that $u_k$ are column vectors.
Question
Looking to show that
$$UU^*= \sum_{k=1}^{m} u_ku_k^*$$
Possible direction
The formula of matrix multiplication:
$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}$$
By substitution for $UU^*$ is:
$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{ik}u^*_{kj}$$
Let's consider the $i,j$ entry of
$$UU^*= \sum_{k=1}^{m} u_ku_k^*$$
By expanding the summation element:
$$u_k u_k^*=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1k} \\
u_{2k} \\
\vdots \\
u_{nk}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{u_{1k}} \
\overline{u_{2k}} \
...\
\overline{u_{nk}}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1k}\overline{u_{1k}} & u_{1k}\overline{u_{2k}} & \cdots & u_{1k}\overline{u_{nk}} \\
u_{2k}\overline{u_{1k}} & u_{2k}\overline{u_{2k}} & \cdots & u_{2k}\overline{u_{nk}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
u_{nk}\overline{u_{1k}} & u_{nk}\overline{u_{2k}} & \cdots & u_{nk}\overline{u_{nk}}
\end{pmatrix}$$
And summing up over the $i,j$ entry of each such element:
$$d_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{ik}\overline{u_{jk}}$$
But the last element indexes $j,k$ are reversed from the above:
$$c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{ik}\overline{u_{kj}}$$
Did I get the indexes wrong? Am I missing something?

I don’t quite understand what you are getting at. The two equalities are unrelated.

@user1551 added more on the original question, to provide better context on this last step.

@Michael As user1551 said, the equality you're trying to prove has nothing to do with the orthonormality of the columns. The equation holds for any $U$; what is special about the case of orthonormal columns is that $UU^*$ is a projection matrix.

@Michael In order to show that matrices $A,B$ are equal, you can show that $A_{ij} = B_{ij}$ for every $i$ and $j$. With that in mind, the next logical step here seems to be finding the $i,j$ entry of $\sum_{k=1}^m u_ku_k^*$ (and seeing that indeed matches your formula for $c_{ij}$). Does that help?

@Michael The way that I think of this result, by the way, is as a consequence of block-matrix multiplication. Note that when $U$ is partitioned into columns and $U^*$ is partitioned into rows, the two partitions are "conformable".

@BenGrossmann Assuming you are correct and the orthonormality of the columns, I've removed this part from the question. Also, explicitly added the $i,j$ entry of $\sum_{k=1}^{m} u_ku_k^*$. I still don't see it.

@Michael There's a mistake with your $c_{ij}$ formula.
$$
c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n [U]{ik}[U^*]{kj}
\ = \sum_{k=1}^n [U_{ik}]\overline{[U]{jk}}
\ = \sum{k=1}^n u_{ik} \overline{u}_{jk}.
$$
Note that $U^*$ is the transpose of the conjugate in this context.

Pasting the comment with the most precise answer:
There's a mistake with the $c_{ij}$ formula.
$$c_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n [U]_{ik}[U^*]_{kj} \\ = \sum_{k=1}^n [U_{ik}]\overline{[U]_{jk}} \\ = \sum_{k=1}^n u_{ik} \overline{u}_{jk}.$$
Note that $U^{∗}$ is the transpose of the conjugate in this context.
